# Primary, secondary and tertiary ticks

Tags: tikz-pgf, ticks

What options exist for adding 3 (or more) different types of ticks to a graph axis? An example of this formatting would be something like what you see on a standard ruler, where you have the major tick (cm) marked with a long line and a number, the minor tick marked with a short line only (mm), and a second type of minor tick marking the half way point between major ticks, which is longer than the minor tick, but shorter than the major one.

[image: ruler]

*edit* Here's an ad hoc solution that works only for simple cases, but will be a coding nightmare for anything even slightly more complex. It's also incapable of more than 3 types of ticks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[xmin=0,xmax=10,
xtick distance=1,
minor x tick num=9,
extra x ticks ={0.5,1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,5.5,6.5,7.5,8.5,9.5},
extra x tick style={major tick length=0.15cm, xticklabels={}},
major tick length=0.2cm,
]
\addplot coordinates {(0,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Ideally a general solution will not need to explicitly list every tertiary tick mark, e.g something like:

```
xtick distance=1, % major tick every 1 inch
minor(type 1) x tick num=1, % minor tick every 1/2 inch
minor(type 2) x tick num=3, % minor tick every 1/4 inch
minor(type 3) x tick num=7, % minor tick every 1/8 inch
minor(type 4) x tick num=15, % minor tick every 1/16 inch
```

Comment: There are lots of options. What do you have so far?

Comment: @Sean Allred I've updated with an ad hoc solution that doesn't address all issues. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: The positions of ticks are calculated by `\pgfplots@prepare@tick@coordlists@for`. Perhaps it is just a matter of copy-paste-rename labor.

Comment: @Symbol 1 I'm not familiar with that, and I can't seem to find any reference to that sort of thing in the pgfplots manual. Do you know of any resources that explain the syntax?

Comment: @Ulysses Such stuff can only be found in the source code. In this case `pgfplotsticks.code.tex`. It is buried somewhere deep in your TeX directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Using dummy axis environment

You can set up exactly the same `axis` environments and ask them to draw different minor ticks for you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % top for inch
    \begin{axis}[
        ytick=\empty,
        axis x line=top,
        x axis line style={-},
        xticklabel={\pgfmathparse{int(\tick/2.54)}$\pgfmathresult$ in},
        xmin=0,xmax=10,
        xtick distance=2.54,
        major tick length=20,
    ]
        \addplot coordinates {(0,0)};
    \end{axis}
    % top for 1/2 inch
    \begin{axis}[
        axis y line=none,
        ytick=\empty,
        axis x line=top,
        x axis line style={draw=none},
        xticklabels={},
        xmin=0,xmax=10,
        xtick distance=2.54,
        major tick length=0,
        minor x tick num=1,
        minor tick length=15,
    ]
        \addplot coordinates {(0,0)};
    \end{axis}
    % top for 1/4 inch
    \begin{axis}[
        axis y line=none,
        ytick=\empty,
        axis x line=top,
        x axis line style={draw=none},
        xticklabels={},
        xmin=0,xmax=10,
        xtick distance=2.54,
        major tick length=0,
        minor x tick num=3,
        minor tick length=10,
    ]
        \addplot coordinates {(0,0)};
    \end{axis}
    % top for 1/8 inch
    \begin{axis}[
        axis y line=none,
        ytick=\empty,
        axis x line=top,
        x axis line style={draw=none},
        xticklabels={},
        xmin=0,xmax=10,
        xtick distance=2.54,
        major tick length=0,
        minor x tick num=7,
        minor tick length=5,
    ]
        \addplot coordinates {(0,0)};
    \end{axis}
    % middle for 50pt
    \begin{axis}[
        ytick=\empty,
        axis x line=middle,
        x axis line style={-},
        xticklabel={\pgfmathparse{int(\tick*28.4527559055+.1)}$\pgfmathresult$pt},
        xmin=0,xmax=10,
        xtick distance=1.7572990176,
        major tick length=20,
    ]
        \addplot coordinates {(0,0)};
    \end{axis}
    % middle for 10pt
    \begin{axis}[
        axis y line=none,
        ytick=\empty,
        axis x line=middle,
        x axis line style={draw=none},
        xticklabels={},
        xmin=0,xmax=10,
        xtick distance=1.7572990176,
        major tick length=0,
        minor x tick num=5,
        minor tick length=10,
    ]
        \addplot coordinates {(0,0)};
    \end{axis}
    % bottom for cm
    \begin{axis}[
        ytick=\empty,
        axis x line=bottom,
        x axis line style={-},
        xticklabel={\pgfmathparse{int(\tick)}\small$\pgfmathresult$cm},
        xmin=0,xmax=10,
        xtick distance=1,
        major tick length=20,
    ]
        \addplot coordinates {(0,0)};
    \end{axis}
    % bottom for .5 cm
    \begin{axis}[
        axis y line=none,
        ytick=\empty,
        axis x line=bottom,
        x axis line style={draw=none},
        xticklabels={},
        xmin=0,xmax=10,
        xtick distance=1,
        major tick length=0,
        minor x tick num=1,
        minor tick length=15,
    ]
        \addplot coordinates {(0,0)};
    \end{axis}
    % bottom for .1 cm
    \begin{axis}[
        axis y line=none,
        ytick=\empty,
        axis x line=bottom,
        x axis line style={draw=none},
        xticklabels={},
        xmin=0,xmax=10,
        xtick distance=1,
        major tick length=0,
        minor x tick num=9,
        minor tick length=10,
    ]
        \addplot coordinates {(0,0)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

## In general

This is just a **Theory**.

## Step 1

First you have to prepare the keys such as

> ```
> /pgfplots/minor x tick num/.initial=0,
> /pgfplots/minor x tick num/.belongs to family=/pgfplots/tick,
> ```

This step is not so hard. But it is a good chance to figure out what kind of interface do you want. Check `pgfplots.code.tex` for samples.

## Step 2 [optional]

Users are allowed to input explicit positions of minor ticks by the key `/pgfplots/minor xtick` or `y` or `z`. If you want to mimic this, you can find the definition of `\pgfplots@init@collect@firstplotastick` in `pgfplots.code.tex`.

There are also miscellaneous keys such as `every minor tick`.

## Step 3 [recommended]

The macro `\pgfplots@check@for@minor@ticks` checks whether the user wants to draw minor ticks. I suspects that it is just a matter of optimization. I highly recommended that you do the same thing for your minorer ticks.

## Step 4

In `pgfplotsticks.code.tex` it defines `\pgfplots@prepare@tick@coordlists@for`. This is an all-in-one macro that calculates the positions of ticks as lists. The complete lists of ticks are then stored in

> ```
> \pgfplots@prepared@tick@positions@minor@x % or y or z
> \pgfplots@prepared@tick@positions@major@x % or y or z
> ```

You need to rewrite this macro.

At this place, we see why [pgfplots](/questions/tagged/pgfplots) refuses to draw minor ticks for uneven major ticks --- `\pgfplots@minor@tick@dist` is a global variable; it does not vary for different major ticks.

## Step 5 [optional]

There are minor ticks for log-plots... If you want to...

## Step 6

Finally we meet `\pgfplots@drawticklines@onorientedsurf@`. It will draw ticks at the prescribed position.

You need to rewrite this macro.

---

That is all I can tell. Be sure to answer your own question once you implement it successfully.